# Android listview with phone number. Want to click and make call or email

Tags: android, listview

I made a listview and have have 2 objects in it, Name & Phone. Now, I want to click the listview and make a phone call with listed phone no.

I dont know how to do. Please help. Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Express extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            activitylink.getInstance().addActivity(this);

            final String Item_Name = "NAME", Item_Hotline = "HOTLINE";

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            String[] hotlines = new String[]{ "11112222" , "22223333", "44445555" };

            for( int i=0;i<getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item).length ; ++i) {
                    HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    item.put(Item_Name,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item)[i]);
                    item.put(Item_Hotline,hotlines[i]);
                    myListData.add(item);
            }

            setListAdapter( new SimpleAdapter(
                    this,
                    myListData,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { Item_Name, Item_Hotline },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 } )
            );
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,Hope this will help you...

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
       String hotline = (String) myListData.get((int) id)
                        .values().toArray()[1];

       Log.d("hotline", hotline);
       callHotline(hotline);
    }
}
private void callHotline(String hotlineStr){ 
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+hotlineStr));
   startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id)
        {
              String hotline = myListData.get(position);

```
          Intent tocall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         tocall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+hotline ));
          startActivity(tocall);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnItemClickListener` :

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + hotlines[position]));
    startActivity(callIntent);

    }
}
```